# SQL Table to another database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have 2 databases on SQL (identical).  I want a table from one database to be copied to the other database.  They are both the same name and the original table can be overwritten.

Comment: What RDBMS and version? Are there any foreign key constraints or Identity columns that need to be considered?

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM `target_database`.`table_name`

INSERT INTO `target_database`.`table_name` SELECT * FROM `source_database`.`table_name`
```

Comment: Don't forget schema should be 'database'.'schema'.'table'

Comment: TRUNCATE `target_database`.`table_name` would be quicker than DELETE FROM.

Comment: DELETE FROM 'SixthSenseUsers','college_survey_questions'
INSERT INTO 'SixthSenseUsers','college_survey_questions' SELECT * FROM 'test','college_survey_questions'


  -----   I put this in but get an error : ---    


Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'SixthSenseUsers'.
Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Line 2: Incorrect syntax near 'test'.

Comment: @Scott - That looks like a Microsoft SQL Server error message? I think Hammerite's answer is using MySQL backticks. You should always state the product that you are using. You don't need any quotes around the object names in that query.

Comment: Try `DELETE FROM SixthSenseUsers.college_survey_questions INSERT INTO SixthSenseUsers.college_survey_questions SELECT * FROM test.college_survey_questions`

Comment: I'm now getting ---  Server: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'SixthSenseUsers.college_survey_questions'  but all the names look correct.

Comment: @Scott - I forgot to add a schema into your query. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the tables in sync continuously, you can use Transactional Replication.It will keep on copying the data from one table one db to another table of other DB.

Refer for further setup details over here:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1438201/Setting-Up-Transactional-Replication-A-Step-by-step-Guide.htm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no computed columns, Identity columns or FK constraints something like the following should work.

```
BEGIN TRAN
DELETE FROM SixthSenseUsers.dbo.college_survey_questions 

INSERT INTO SixthSenseUsers.dbo.college_survey_questions 

SELECT * FROM test.dbo.college_survey_questions

COMMIT
```